# Bar Graphs in c#

Tags: c#, graph

I am trying to implement a bar graph in C#. I have two textboxes in which i get data and i want to plot a comparison bar graph for them. For example, i have a original cpu(ocpu) and changed cpu (ccpu) data coming and i want to plot a comparison graph for them.
I am able to do so, as in the picture graph.The blue is original value and orange is changed value. But, i am getting 0,1,2 in the X axis which i don't require. I also dont require the line between those two bars. I have attached the code snippet also that i am using. I have two series called "Original" and "modified" in the graph.

```
chartcpu.Series["Original"].Points.AddY(ocpu.Text.ToString());
chartcpu.Series["Modified"].Points.AddY(ccpu.Text.ToString());
chartcpu.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "CPU";
```

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLSSH.png)
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOvUl.png)

Please let me know what is a solution to this ?

--Samir Singh

Comment: Why are you converting your _y_ value to a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not completly sure if i unterstood you corretly but with this code:

```
        var original = chart1.Series.Add("Original");
        var modified = chart1.Series.Add("Modified");
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;

        original.Points.AddXY("CPU", 7.6);
        modified.Points.AddXY("CPU", 1.6);
```

you get this result:

[image]

You may post a "how it should be" sketch (with paint or whatever) if you want to achieve something different.

Greetings from germany

**UPDATE:**

> 1. I have my data coming from a textbox, is it not OK to convert it to string for display. This is a comment mentioned above. What form do i need to convert it to ?

string is just text and the chart expects floating-point numbers as seen on the YValues Property of the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint`:

`public double[] YValues { get; set; }`

`Points.AddXY` already does the conversion for you as its also handles `DateTime` or `DBNull` etc.
If you want to you can handle the conversion yourself by using `Double.TryParse`.

> 2. what is the meaning of "AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;". I think this was missing in my code.

Well yes, the major and minor grid properties control the appearance of the lines from the specified axis. By disabling them you simply turn them off.

> 3. How do i change the colour and width of the bars here

Series and DataPoint both have the Color-Property so you can say:

```
chartcpu.Series["Original"].Color = Color.Magenta;
chartcpu.Series["Modified"].Color = Color.Lime;
```

Or whatever color you prefer :)

The size is change like this:

```
chartcpu.Series["Original"].SetCustomProperty("PointWidth", "2");
chartcpu.Series["Modified"].SetCustomProperty("PointWidth", "2");
```

> If my data is empty, i want to display no bar. Now is shows 0.

When i do not specify any data my chart is empty. But you can try to only add a point if you have valid data:

```
// e.g. when ocpu text change
chartcpu.Series["Original"].Points.Clear();
double yValue = 0;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ocpu.Text) && Double.TryParse(ocpu.Text, out yValue))
{
    chartcpu.Series["Original"].Points.AddXY("CPU", yValue);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> how to change the value that is shown on the Left Grids in K format,
>   for e.g - if it is 12000000, I want it to be displayed as 12000K/12M.
>   Also, how do I format the value shown above the bar having a separator
>   for 1000 e.g if the value is 112887296 as 112,887,296 or
>   112,887K/113M(approximated )

*Simple approach:*
Add this to your initialization logic:

```
//string format = "#,0.#0"; // default
//string format = "#,0,.#0K"; // thousand
string format = "#,0,,.#0M"; // million, etc.
cpuchart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = format;
cpuchart.Series.ToList().ForEach(series => series.LabelFormat = format);
```

Custom Numeric Format on msdn: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

*Dynamic approach:*
Add a Dictionary for your suffixes as a static variable:

```
private static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<int, string> _numberSuffix = new ReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>(new Dictionary<int, string> {
        { 0, String.Empty }, // default
        { 1, "K" }, // thousand
        { 2, "M" }, // million
        { 3, "B" }, // billion
        { 4, "T" }, // trillion
    });
```

and a method for formatting your chart:

```
private void FormatChart(Chart chart)
{
    // calculates the format based on the maximum on the y axis
    chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale(); // ensure that the maximum of the y-axis is calculated
    int digitGroupCount = (int)Math.Log10(Math.Abs(chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum)) / 3;
    string suffix = _numberSuffix.ContainsKey(digitGroupCount) ? _numberSuffix[digitGroupCount] : "nA";
    string format = String.Format("#,0{0}.#0{1}", new string(',', digitGroupCount), suffix);
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = format;
    chart.Series.ToList().ForEach(series => series.LabelFormat = format);
}
```

Now you can call this method whenever you want to format your chart (e.g. when a value changed)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the way i want the o/p. I have few questions though.1. I have my data coming from a textbox, is it not OK to convert it to string for display. This is a comment mentioned above. What form do i need to convert it to ?  2.what is the meaning of "AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;". I think this was missing in my code.

Comment: 3. How do i change the colour and width of the bars here .If my data is empty, i want to display no bar. Now is shows 0.i am not from C# background and i am from DBA background, but trying to develop a application in C#, so sorry for such basic questions -Samir Singh

Comment: Hello Samir, i updated my answer. Please feel free to ask further questions or accept my answer if it was helpful. Greetings

Comment: Hi Bashn, Thanks for the answers. I tested the solutions provided by you. They work as i expected. Thanks for the answers and bearing me for my basic questions !! .I will post further questions in case i need help.

Comment: Hi Bashn, can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Hi Samir, how to do what? selfish gues: take a look at this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :) - thanks mate

Comment: Thanks Bashn, I have accepted you answer. What I meant above is the same you answered - "how to accept your answer". Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Bashn, how to change the value that is shown on the Left Grids in K format, for e.g - if it is 12000000, I want it to be displayed as 12000K/12M. Also, how do I format the value shown above the bar having a separator for 1000 e.g if the value is 112887296 as 112,887,296 or 112,887K/113M(approximated )

Comment: Hi Bashn, i noticed that if the value of a column is 3, then also it converts it to 0.003 as we have given a static format. To make it dynamic, do i have to use the other approach you mentioned or is there a simpler approach ? I can check the value using a If condition and use different formats right ?

Comment: Ay - as you said you can make a if condition based on the actual `.AxisY.Maximum` or whatever and use your indiv. formats (or use one of the commented formats in the simple approach). You may find `AxisY.Maximum` being `Double.NaN`, be sure then that you set the values and may call `cpuchart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();`

Comment: Thanks Bashn. I used the If condition statements to use different format as you suggetsed. It works. I would need another help here. Is there a way I can change the position of the labels shown on the Bar ? By default, it is displayed at the top of the bar. But, they overlap with each other in the chat. So, I want to display one of them at the middle or at the right of the chart.

Comment: Hi Samir. The overlapping behavior is controlled by the properties of the `cpuchart.Series["<SeriesName>"].SmartLabelStyle` property. Make sure `cpuchart.Series["<SeriesName>"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled` is set to `true` (which it schould be by default) and play with the other settings of `SmartLabelStyle`.