# I am trying to create chart in c# from non-constant values in an array

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I am loading csv file values in array and want to create a chart.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            int x = sum[i];
            chart1.Series.Add(array[0, i]);
            chart1.Series[array[0, i]].Points.AddXY(i, x.ToString());
        }
```

only last bar is showing as output correctly.

[image: IMG1]

here is csv file snapshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCrPO.png)

when i tried with hardcoded values like

```
chart1.Series["S1"].Points.AddXY(1.ToString(), 99);
        chart1.Series["S1"].Points.AddXY(2.ToString(), 88);
        chart1.Series["S1"].Points.AddXY(3.ToString(), 33);
```

it was showing correct output as shown in snapshot.

[hardcoded values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo3OM.png)

Comment: Can you add the `csv` input for reference, or at least a sample? Are yo sure the other values are not zero?

Comment: yes 100%. infact i have been trying it for days and i have tried it with hardcoded valuse and constant integers, it worked but it is not working with non constant values.

Comment: Can you add in the hardcoded example for comparison? And to give us more to help you out.

Comment: please see the edited post.

Comment: _x.ToString()_ Not so. You need numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the syntax used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835300/3923163) for a bar chart. There is also an update to your sum function, since I don't know other ways to sum the columns of a 2D array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) {
                x += array[j, i]
            }
            chart1.Series.Add(array[0, i]);
            chart1.Points.AddXY(array[0, i], x);
        }
```